# Pandas Datetime: Calculate Number of Weeks Between Dates in Two Columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with two columns that contain dates, and I want to create a new columns whose value is the number of months between those dates.

```
>df

Index   Date1         Date2
1       2012/03/07    2013/03/16
2       2012/12/05    2012/12/25
3       2010/06/30    2013/05/19
4       2002/11/02    2011.06.08


df["Date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"])
df["Date2"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"])
```

Date1 will always be before date2. My current method of doing this requires about 10 steps, and I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do this. Thoughts?

Comment: in your title you put weeks, while the text has months?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see this link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas

```
(df['Date2']-df['Date1']).apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
```

for numpy >=1.7 (see the link if you are using 1.6.1)

I am not sure what it will do with the fraction. (usually I would divide by `np.timedelta64(1,'D')` then divide by say 30 to make a fractional num of months (as a float)

Comment: fyi....the title of your issue says weeks, but in the text you said months (if weeks then just use 'W' instead of 'M'), or use days and divide by 7

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to do it in python but the steps I would do:

- Convert dates into number of days since the epoch
- Subtract date1 from date2
- Divide by 7

Comment: that is probably not at all what he should do in python ... but it would work

Comment: "She"... Not all of us are male.